# Using bluetooth on iOS

Tags: ios, linux, windows, bluetooth

Is it possible to use bluetooth to communicate with a pc application, not just on OSX, but linux and windows as well? Basically I just want the ability to tap a button on an iOS app and have something change on the pc app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two legal  options to communicate using bluetooth :

**GameKit.Framework** : This framework only used for the iOS to iOS file transfer so off course this will not suit for your requirement.

**CoreBluetooth.framework** : This is Bluetooth low energy framework which can be used with your mac but remember that in this case your mac can only work in the central mode . Just read some tutorials about the corebluetooth framework and see whether it is helpful to you .

Comment: How about communicating with a linux pc via CoreBluetooth.framework?